# Background image disappears after add some styles

Tags: html, css

pardon me if my question is stupid, I'm quick new to all these technologies. my objective is to add image-background in it default size while it doesn't zoom since it is a big size picture, the problem is when I add some styles, the image doesn't show up and background getting blank.
by the way, IM using particle.js on top of this background image.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Infinite Space !</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body >
  <div id="particles-js"></div>

  //particle-js configues
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
      console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
      });
  </script>


  </div>
</body>
</html>



 #particles-js{

  background: url("https://d14xs1qewsqjcd.cloudfront.net/assets/bg-header-star.jpg")
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /* background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didnt add a semicolon after the background property:

```
#particles-js{

  background: url("https://d14xs1qewsqjcd.cloudfront.net/assets/bg-header-star.jpg") /* <---- Semicolon goes here*/
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  /* background-attachment: fixed;  /* Also you didnt close this comment */
}
```